# Lotus Quick Places Issuee

Tags: lotus

After logging with user first, middle and last name of the user in quickr, the quickr home page is displayed. Then I will click the places, and they are not showing and instead I get this error.  How can fix this problem?

```
'performance' is null or not an object
'window.q_BaseLoader.performance' is null or not an object
'dojo' is undefined
'window.q_BaseLoader.performance' is null or not an object
'window.q_BaseLoader.sametime' is null or not an object
'dojo' is undefined
'q_BaseLoader' is undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you installed Sametime and Quickr (or Quick Place?) on the same server. This is not a supported configuration. And now you know why...